# Multiple pages in the same PDF reporting with PDFsharp

Tags: pdfsharp, multipage, migradoc

I am getting values from database and collection of all values are larger than a single page. Number of pages are unknown and it might differ report by report. Currently, only 1 page of multiple pages is being printed but same information in every pages. I want continuous information in the pages not same information in every page. How can I do that with PDFsharp?

Here I am giving my codes to understand...

```
        Document doc = new Document();

        //Create table
        var sec = doc.AddSection();
        var table = sec.AddTable();
        table.Format.Font.Size = 6;
        table.Borders.Distance = 0;
        table.Borders.Color = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors.DarkGray;
        var renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
        renderer.PrepareDocument();
        int totalPage = renderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount;

            for (int i = 1; i <= totalPage; ++i)
            {

                PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
                renderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromMillimeter(10), XUnit.FromMillimeter(10), XUnit.FromMillimeter(double.MaxValue), table);
                gfx.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have MigraDoc create the whole document without a for loop:

```
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always); 
renderer.Document = document; 
renderer.RenderDocument();
```

Your for loop has a variable `i` that is not used in your code. If you want to do it the complicated way, use `RenderPage` instead of `RenderObject`.

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this may be of help to anyone but if you want to break your table into multiple pages you can use this method:

```
    public Document MultiplePagesPerDocument(Document document, DocumentForm documentForm, Section section, DocumentPage page, DataTable dt, int maxTableRows)
    {
        _document = document;

        if (dt.Rows.Count > maxTableRows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // Break the table onto next page for maxTableRows
                if (i % maxTableRows == 0)
                {
                    section = _document.LastSection;
                    section.AddPageBreak();

                    Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
                    paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = "3cm";

                    _position = new PageItemPosition()
                    {
                        Height = "3.0cm",
                        Width = "8.0cm",
                        Top = "3.0cm",
                        LeftPosition = ShapePosition.Left,
                        TopPosition = ShapePosition.Top
                    };

                    object tableSection = page.AddPageTextFrame(section, _position, string.Empty);

                    documentForm.GenerateSection(section, tableSection, 170, "Table", dt);
                }
            }
        }

        return this._document;
    }
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer to the question. This is not the way MigraDoc should be used - MigraDoc adds page breaks automatically when used as intended. As long as you do not disclose the source for `AddPageTextFrame` and `GenerateSection` this answer is useless.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.